# If cursor is empty / null

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

If cursor is empty/null , I want to add a row .

But the code I use doesnt work : (error: index -1 requested with a size of 1)

```
               final String query = "SELECT  category.CategoryID, " +
                        "category.Title, category.ParentID " +
                        " FROM category" +
                        " WHERE category.Title = '"+ _TopCategory  
                        +"'";

                Cursor cursorKayita = db.rawQuery(query, null);

                if ( cursorKayita.moveToFirst() ) {
                    // start activity 
                } else {
                _Categories.put("Title", _TopCategory);
                 db.insert("category", null, _Categories);  

                }
```

Comment: Please post a stack trace from your Logcat.

Comment: Nothing in this code should throw that error... What are you leaving out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a line that make that questions to the cursor

```
try{
   Lite = open_bd(); //Open database
   Cursor x = Lite.query(/*Your query*/);

   if (x.getCount() != 0 && x != null) {
      x.moveToFirst();
      //Do your activity
   }else{
      _Categories.put("Title", _TopCategory);
      db.insert("category", null, _Categories);  
   }
}catch (Exception error) {
   //Whatever with your error
} finally {
   Lite.close();
}
```

That is how I manage the cursors, cause I´ve found out that they are very unstable when you ask if the cursos is null. They can be empty but not always null

:D Hope it helps

---

When you are managing cursors and databases lenght always do something like

```
where (cursor.getCount() < Xnumber){
   //code
}
```

Same thing as in the if, you should use "less-than" instead of "less-or-equal-than" because the cursors and the databases start reading from -1 index.

Look at this for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.getCount(); i++) {
   if (x.getInt(1) == 0) {
      //CODE
   }
   x.moveToNext();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> index -1 requested with a size of 1

This is a CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException.  The only time that you will [see this error](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/database/AbstractCursor.java#AbstractCursor.checkPosition%28%29) is when you try to read data from a Cursor without calling `moveToFirst()` (or a similar `moveTo___()` method).  But nowhere in the code that you posted are you trying to read from the Cursor...

The good news is that the LogCat errors give you the line number where this error occurred, if you need help reading the LogCat, click ["edit"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15838041/edit) under your question to post it.